# Addressing a styling issue not accessable from QT Designer

Tags: user-interface, qt4, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am working on a QTreeWidget and I can't see a property for column size in the `edit items...` context menu. So I guess the cleanest way to perform this step is to attach application code to a signal (and not inheritance).

What signal do I attach to. More specifically, What signal should I attach to, to execute code that should be part of visual styling which should be editable from a GUI Builder, but isn't, or is to elaborate to model in a GUI builder. I guess i'm looking for a signal that is a one off call meant for further styling.

**edit:**

I guess I'll stick to inheritance, still if I shouldn't, or if there is indeed a one-off signal please post, and state merits :D

Comment: Isn't a simple call to [setColumnWidth](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtreeview.html#setColumnWidth) good enough?

Comment: yes, I am using that now. Wish I could close the question.

Comment: @HassanSyed. So long as the question has no answers, you should be able to delete it using the `delete` link beneath the tags.